# Creating canvas inside the leaflet popup is not working fine

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, gis

I need help about [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) for my app.Firstly let me explain my problem,
I insert the [Chart JS](http://www.chartjs.org/) element inside the marker popup.When I clicked on a marker,it is showing me all `DOM` elements which I created the elements for popup.But when I click other marker before close current popup,`Chart` element is not working fine.the fail occuring only for `Chart` elements.. not other `DOM` elements..
The screenshot of what I'm trying to tell is as follows.
First image explain when I click on a marker while all popups all closed.

[image]

Second image is when a marker is open..

[image]

This canvas element is my Chart element as you know.

```
let title="<div style='margin-left:10px;'><canvas style='clear:both; 
position: relative;' id='myChart'></canvas></div>";

let marker = L.marker([parseFloat(poiData.lat), parseFloat(poiData.lon)],{
  data:{poiData,polyline}
});

marker.unbindPopup().bindPopup(title, { 
  autoPan:true,
  maxWidth: "auto"
}).openPopup();

marker.addTo(this.iconLayer);

marker.on("click", (event: MouseEvent) => {
  let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Grafik',
        data: [2, 29, 5, 5, 2, 3, 10],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true
    }
  });
});
```

Can you please suggest me any way to solve this problem?

Comment: seems like a binding problem. your values are bind to the previous marker. Your addTo event is not firing. Try to look into chart js for this

Comment: you are right because all markers's canvas id are same.I solved the problem giving them different id,But I think it is not a good way (best) to solve this problem..

Comment: yes, you should not use the same id for all. Best solution would be to track the element on which you clicked and select canvas from the click event rather than selecting it with document.getElementById()

Comment: I would suggest destroying the canvas and clearing the chart whenever a popup is closed, for good measure. The overhead of creating a new `<canvas>` element for each popup is very small nowadays.

Comment: thank you both, it seems destroying the canvas is better way for my problem.